# Get indoor position from a network scan data

Tags: here-api

I checked the documentation of the API of HERE Positioning. To get the indoor position using Network Wi-Fi I used PositioningManager.LocationMethod.

But this method is used only to get the position from a scan using the device.

For me, I have  a json already that contain a scan ( measures of RSSI and macs ). Is there any function that take that Radio scan as parameter and  gives you the position, the venue associated and the floor ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Withing the HERE Premium Mobile SDK this is not possible, the SDK has it's own scanning logic implemented which cannot be overridden. The HERE Positioning REST API ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/dev_guide/topics/supported-network-technologies.html)) could be alternative. It would give back the position (coordinate) however the associated venue and floor are not available via the REST API at the moment.